# Fancybox can't reopen popup: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, fancybox

Using latest [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and jQuery 2.2.3 I'm trying to open a "child" popup by pressing a button in "parent" popup, and reopen parent popup after closing the child popup.

By themselves, popups open and close just fine. But when I try to go reopen parent, it shows for a second, then disappears with a message in console: *"jquery.fancybox.pack.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null"*. Which happens to point to this: `this.overlay.width(a).height("100%");`

When I try to reopen parent manually, intstead I see a popup with "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

I've tried two approaches, both fail similarly

(.fancybox-to-form is a button inside parent, by pressing which you open child):

1)

```
$(".fancybox-to-form").on("click", function(){
    var parentPopup = $(this).closest(".wall-popup");

    $.fancybox.open( $("#popup-form"), {        
        afterClose: function(){
            $.fancybox.open( {href: '#wall-popup--1'} );
        }
    } );
});
```

2)

```
$(".fancybox-to-form").fancybox({
    afterClose: function(){
        var parentPopup = $(this.element).closest(".wall-popup");
        $.fancybox.open( parentPopup );
    }
});
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to setTimeout for the 2nd fancybox. (~100ms)
Maybe the 1st fancybox is not closed completely at the time the 2nd is displayed.